# Is it possible to execute your code on visual studio without the cmd lines?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Pretty much the title, I'm trying to get rid of what's highlighted in red.

[image]

Comment: Install the Python extension and run your code with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install an extension like [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), which renders in the console.

You can execute your code by clicking on the "play" symbol which should now be available:

[image: Execute Code]

Comment: Oh sorry. Maybe the solution is in the link I just pasted there now. https://www.programmersought.com/article/3680252795/ - (I'll remove the link from the answer and leave it here)